# Replace RandomAccessFile with AudioRecord Android

Tags: java, audio-recording, randomaccessfile

I'm using deepspeech's tflite model and doing speech to text with a wav file, as their [documentation](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_downloads/385531d702f87fbf1d7b341ead3f68c3/DeepSpeechActivity.java) uses `RandomAccessFile` to read the wav file:

```
 private void doInference(String audioFile) {
    long inferenceExecTime = 0;

    this._startInference.setEnabled(false);

    this.newModel(this._tfliteModel.getText().toString());

    this._tfliteStatus.setText("Extracting audio features ...");

    try {
        RandomAccessFile wave = new RandomAccessFile(audioFile, "r");

        wave.seek(20); char audioFormat = this.readLEChar(wave);
        assert (audioFormat == 1); // 1 is PCM
        // tv_audioFormat.setText("audioFormat=" + (audioFormat == 1 ? "PCM" : "!PCM"));

        wave.seek(22); char numChannels = this.readLEChar(wave);
        assert (numChannels == 1); // MONO
        // tv_numChannels.setText("numChannels=" + (numChannels == 1 ? "MONO" : "!MONO"));

        wave.seek(24); int sampleRate = this.readLEInt(wave);
        assert (sampleRate == this._m.sampleRate()); // desired sample rate
        // tv_sampleRate.setText("sampleRate=" + (sampleRate == 16000 ? "16kHz" : "!16kHz"));

        wave.seek(34); char bitsPerSample = this.readLEChar(wave);
        assert (bitsPerSample == 16); // 16 bits per sample
        // tv_bitsPerSample.setText("bitsPerSample=" + (bitsPerSample == 16 ? "16-bits" : "!16-bits" ));

        wave.seek(40); int bufferSize = this.readLEInt(wave);
        assert (bufferSize > 0);
        // tv_bufferSize.setText("bufferSize=" + bufferSize);

        wave.seek(44);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
        wave.readFully(bytes);

        short[] shorts = new short[bytes.length/2];
        // to turn bytes to shorts as either big endian or little endian.
        ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shorts);

        this._tfliteStatus.setText("Running inference ...");

        long inferenceStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // sphinx-doc: java_ref_inference_start
        String decoded = this._m.stt(shorts, shorts.length);
        // sphinx-doc: java_ref_inference_stop

        inferenceExecTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - inferenceStartTime;

        this._decodedString.setText(decoded);
```

I want to work with the data from the microphone, how do I do it with `AudioRecord`

Comment: That's not documentation. That's a random Java source file. Do you have any official docs on this library you're using? That's probably the first step, as the relevant function might take an interface type that you can adapt `AudioRecord` to.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo oh sorry they instructed to use the tflite pattern [here](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Java-Examples.html) but it looks little, however i found another source here it looks like it will handle with data from mic but i still can't run it.